# Why does aqueous NaCl conduct electricity?

Tags: electrochemistry, aqueous-solution, electrolysis

Could someone please explain why an aqueous solution of NaCl conducts electricity? I've Googled this up but couldn't get a satisfactory answer. This has an answer on Physics.SE but that's too complicated. My textbook doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Essentially you understand that it is because it dissociates, and your follow-up question is why it dissociates, which, as someone else pointed out, is another question.

Comment: See the answer, and linked reference therein, by @M.Farooq: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/118441/79678.

Answer (score 4):

*Original Question:*
Why an aqueous solution of $\ce{NaCl}$ conducts electricity

Because $\ce{NaCl}$ is an electrolyte. This means it yields ions in solution.

Simply put, solid $\ce{NaCl}$ consists of $\ce{Na+}$ cations and $\ce{Cl-}$  anions bound together in a rigid crystal lattice. When it melts or is dissolved in water, the crystal lattice breaks. The ions are now able to move around. Similar to charged particles in a metal conductor (in this case electrons), in liquid form or aqueous solution the ions are the charged particles that can move, allowing the solution to conduct electricity.

*Follow-up question:*
Why $\ce{NaCl}$ dissociates in water

The (rather oversimplified) answer is that dissociation of an ionic compound is facilitated by ion-dipole attractions between the ions of the compound and the polar water molecules.

The water molecules (dipoles) are attracted to the ions  and cause the crystal lattice to destabilize and ions to dissociate. The charged ions in solution are surrounded and stabilized by the water molecules (dipoles).

Note: Some ions migrate as ion pairs, but for a strong electrolyte most or all the ions will be dissociated and surrounded by water molecules.

[image: Dissociation of NaCl in water]

As you seem dissatisfied with the answers received so far, I assume you want to fully understand the mechanism involved in dissociation. Unfortunately, this is rather complex.

There is an excellent  paper by Ballard & Dellago [1] that explains their work on the subject, but you will probably need a bit more physical chemistry / thermodynamics knowledge to understand it fully.

*Reference*

1. Ballard, AJ & Dellago, C "Toward the Mechanism of Ionic Dissociation in Water," *J. Phys. Chem. *B 2012, 116, 45, 13490–13497
   Publication Date:October 19, 2012
   https://doi.org/10.1021/jp309300b

Answer (score 0):

NaCl is an electrolyte. When in solution it dissociates into Na+ and Cl-. When you put electrodes in the solution, the cations are drawn to the cathode and the anions to the anode. This movement produces a current and that is why NaCl solutions can conduct electricity.

Comment: Why does it dissociate?

Comment: I think this answer needs some elaboration. Does this only work with AC? If not, what happens with DC when the bulk of  the ions have already migrated?

Comment: With a DC current, you'll probably get some electrolysis of water and possible oxidation of the chloride (which helps by removing negative charge from the positive electrode).

Comment: @Zhe Agreed. I was just trying to prompt the psoter into fleshing out his answer for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

$\ce{NaCl}$ dissociates into $\ce{Na+}$ and $\ce{Cl-}$ when it dissolves into water. Hydration stabilizes the ions formed. There is $\delta+$ charge on hydrogens of water and $\delta-$ charge on the atoms of oxygen. When $\ce{NaCl}$ is dissolved into water, the hydrogens are attracted to the $\ce{Cl-}$ ions and oxygen atoms to the $\ce{Na+}$ ions. Thus water molecules surround and separate the ions.

[image]

Hence, in an aqueous solution of $\ce{NaCl}$, there are positive and negative ions available to move freely (of course with some resistance due to other molecules in vicinity). When a potential difference is applied, the positive ions are attracted to the negative terminal and vice versa. Thus, a current is established.

Comment: @Abcd See this video on YouTube. [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EBfGcTAJF4o)

Comment: I do not think that actual $\ce{OH-}$ ions are attracted to $\ce{Na+}$ because  the dissociation constant of water is quite low, $pK_w = 14$. So, I don't think that free $H+$ and $OH-$ ions are available. A water molecule as a whole orients itself in a particular way and surrounds the ions.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean that $OH-$ ions are not attracted to $Na+$ but I think that the effect wouldn't be as much.

Comment: Thankyou. So can we say that dissociation of NaCl takes place because of orientation of water molecules?

Comment: And where did u get that awesome picture from ?

Comment: Yes. I think so.

Comment: I googled it(images).

Comment: The simple answer is that water molecules have a dipole. The hydrogen atoms are slightly positively charged and the oxygen atoms slightly negatively charged. So, as you can see in the diagram above, water molecules around positively charged sodium orient themselves such that the oxygen is closer to sodium than the hydrogens. This is known as an ion-dipole interaction. The opposite is true for chlorine. @Abcd

Comment: @orthocresol and therfore they dissociate ?

Comment: @Abcd yes. In the absence of water, NaCl does not dissociate, because it is held together by ionic bonds. The dissociation of NaCl in water also requires the breakage of ionic bonds, but that is compensated for the formation of such ion-dipole interactions, which is the driving force for the dissociation.

Comment: @orthocresol sorry if i am troubling you by questioning too much .. what do u mean by driven by and how does the bond break?

Comment: @Abcd Ionic bonds are only electrostatic forces of attraction. From physics, you will know that the strength of such forces depend on the distance between the two charged species. In solid NaCl, the ions are close to each other, so a bond is said to exist. In aqueous NaCl, the ions are separated from each other, so the bond is said to be broken. A driving force simply refers to something that favours a process. So, the dissociation process is favoured by the fact that ion-dipole interactions are formed.

Answer (score -1):

$\ce{NaCl}$ is strongly ionic compound. It gets completely ionized and dissociates in $\ce{Na+}$ and $\ce{Cl-}$. Both $\ce{Na+}$ and $\ce{Cl-}$ are surrounded by water molecules, $\ce{Na+}$ is surrounded with $\ce{O}$ of $\ce{H2O}$ facing towards $\ce{Na+}$, similarly $\ce{Cl-}$ is surrounded by $\ce{H2O}$ molecules with $\ce{H}$ facing towards $\ce{Cl-}$. Presence of positive and negative ions helps in conduction of electricity.

When electrodes are inserted and current is passed through these electrodes, movement of ions in opposite direction creates current.

After passing current for a long time (especially DC current), the concentration of $\ce{Cl-}$ ions will decrease. The concentration of $\ce{OH-}$ will increase gradually and there will be competition between $\ce{Cl-}$ and $\ce{OH-}$.

Electrolysis of $\ce{NaCl}$

Anode: $\ce{2 Cl- -> Cl2 + 2 e-}\quad E=-1.36\ \mathrm V$

Cathode: $\ce{H2O + 2 e- -> H2 + 2 OH-}\quad E=-0.83\ \mathrm V$

Electrolysis of $\ce{NaOH}$

Anode: $\ce{4 OH- -> O2 + 2 H2O + 2 e-}\quad E=-0.40\ \mathrm V$

Cathode: $\ce{H2O + 2 e- -> H2 + 2 OH-}\quad E=-0.83\ \mathrm V$

After Sufficient long time there will be competition between $\ce{Cl-}$ and $\ce{OH-}$ to get oxidized on Anode, whereas there is only one possible reaction on cathode. Reaction on Anode depends upon the concentration and reduction potential of $\ce{Cl-}$ and $\ce{OH-}$. Actually on cathode there is also possibility of reduction of $\ce{Na+}$ but reduction potential is $-2.7\ \mathrm V$ which is difficult than $\ce{H2O}$ so only one reaction takes place on cathode.