# Non-zero current flow through an electrolytic cell, when an electric potential lesser than that needed for electrolysis is applied?

Tags: electrochemistry, electrolysis

For instance, the potential needed for water splitting is $\pu{1.23V}$. However, there is current flow even at lower potentials (say $\pu{0.5V}$). Clearly, there is no redox reaction happening in the cell as evidenced by lack of bubbles. What is the cause of this current?

Answer (score 2):

As you noticed there is a small amount of current which keeps on flowing when there is no electrolytic decomposition. This "problem" is aptly named as *non*-Faradaic current. Faradaic current refers to current due to oxidation and reduction. Here is a detailed review: [The difference between Faradaic and Nonfaradaic processes in Electrochemistry](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.02930)